# SignalR connection error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have a simple chat client project running using SignalR and MVC which is almost identical to the [ASP.Net One](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) (I'm just experimenting - the client code is identical). I've wired up the following to watch things as they occur:

```
$.connection.hub.stateChanged(function(state){console.log(state)});
```

The connections are working fine but I've noticed that if I shut down IIS Express and watch the console in Chrome, I see this:

```
//As you would expect the state goes from connected to connecting
Object {oldState: 1, newState: 2}

//Then it times out after about 30 secs and throws this awesomeness at the console
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:61623/signalr?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=VDF640emz7PFMToC6vxle_5-7QS5dZMszV4SPbQO7EFEmSSsITnwKsZreqfl4MGq8TXitG2xB5F-2ZdHp-2t3shPzN2hemTY1ZmEWlB8NOn5orUVexaSoARk9XjEO5B00&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D&messageId=B%2C7%7CL%2C0%7CM%2C0%7CN%2C0&tid=0' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established. jquery.signalR-1.0.1.js:1117

//Reconnecting to Disconnecting - so why the error above?
Object {oldState: 2, newState: 4} 

//Then radio silence if I start IIS again...
```

2 Questions:

How do I avoid the Error when an attempted reconnection fails?

Why doesn't SignalR continue to try and connect to IIS? I was under the impression this was the point of the technology...

EDIT: the same thing happens in FireFox too

Comment: Not sure if this will help your problem. https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Configuring-SignalR

Comment: @TimBJames - thanks Tim, that's really just to do with it timing out, I don't mind it timing out if the server explodes and stops responding, I would just like to handle the client side error gracefully :-)

Comment: Stick the link to this question in [JabbR](https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/signalr) as there might be someone in there that could help.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: No, I think from memory I just put a try/catch system in and restarted the connection if it was dead. Actually the answer below is exactly what I did.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eventually, the connection will die and stop retrying.  You can have it continuously reconnect with this method from the SignalR Docs.

[How to continuously reconnect](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#continuousreconnect)

> How to continuously reconnect
>
> In some applications you might want to automatically re-establish a
>   connection after it has been lost and the attempt to reconnect has
>   timed out. To do that, you can call the Start method from your Closed
>   event handler (disconnected event handler on JavaScript clients). You
>   might want to wait a period of time before calling Start in order to
>   avoid doing this too frequently when the server or the physical
>   connection are unavailable. The following code sample is for a
>   JavaScript client using the generated proxy.

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $.connection.hub.start();
   }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
});
```